# use js to simulate the zoom in action on google books page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In this [google books page](https://books.google.com/books?id=KuDuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PR8&dq=cantor%20dedekind%20axiom&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzg_DexKnXAhVD92MKHQReBRgQ6AEITTAF#v=onepage&q=cantor%20dedekind%20axiom&f=false), I want to use js to simulate the full-screen action,

```
document.getElementById(':2').click()
```

it didn't work, why and how to fix?
[image]